# Modern Site Page - Missing "total page Views" and "Save for later" option in Office 365 SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

I created a modern page in Sharepoint online , and in the end  i am able to see only Likes and comments options. I am not able to see "Views" and "Save for Later" options. Do i need to enable anything ? Please help.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to enable something. When there is other users who view the page, it will display Views section.

Comment: that means , if  other users visits the page then "Views" will automatically shows ? and currently it is not showing because no one visits it ?

Comment: Hello, I checked again ... few people visited the page but still it is not showing. Can you please help here ?